# Simple form submit with conditional redirect?

Tags: php, forms

I'm building a license agreement page in which a single checkbox is used to signal "I have read the license and agree to abide by the terms, etc".

Below this is a button labeled "I Accept".

I need to hook this button to a function at the top of this php page that (1) checks to insure that the checkbox is checked and if not, prompts an alert "You must agree to the license to continue". (2) If the checkbox is checked, it redirects them to 1 of 4 links depending on the value in $_GET['productid'].

I will use a php switch statement for the redirect and I'm asking to see what options i have for the submit button to call the function without passing the submit off to another script.

```
<form action="?">
    <div class="accept">
        <input type="checkbox" id="accept" /><label for="accept">Yes. I Have Read and I Agree to This License Agreement and Terms of Service</label>
        <p><input type="submit" value=" I ACCEPT " /></p>
    </div>
</form>

<?php
function go(){

$id = $_GET['productid'];

    switch ($id)
    {
    case 1:
        //product 1
        header("Location: link-to-url1");
    break;
    case 2:
        //product2
        header("Location: link-to-url2");
        break;
    case 3:
        //product3
        header("Location: link-to-url3");
        break;
    case 4:
        //product4
        header("Location: link-to-url4");
        break;

    default:
        //default
        header("Location: link-to-url-default");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You can change the form action via JavaScript, or you can send the data to another page via cURL when hit

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$id = (int) $_GET['productid'];

switch ($id)
{
    case 1:
        //product 1
        $url = 'link-to-url1';
        break;
    case 2:
        //product2
        $url = 'link-to-url2';
        break;
    case 3:
        //product3
        $url = 'link-to-url3';
        break;
    case 4:
        //product4
        $url = 'link-to-url4';
        break;

    default:
        //default
        $url = 'link-to-url-default';
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $url; ?>">
    <div class="accept">
        <input type="checkbox" id="accept" /><label for="accept">Yes. I Have Read and I Agree to This License Agreement and Terms of Service</label>
        <p><input type="submit" value=" I ACCEPT " /></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: may be it could be optimized a bit?

Comment: The fact that the links are coming from a form submit, I believe is throwing off the paypal gateway. I believe I will have to do a location redirect and not a form submit. eg, I'm getting the paypal login screen and not the normal sales page I get when I paste the link directly into the browser's address bar.